How can I ensure that Python 3.11 is installed on my machine? (Windows 10)
I have downloaded and installed Python 3.11 via 64 bit exe installer, but when I run python -v its showing that Python version 3.10 is installed:

After the installation was complete, there was no message about restarting my system in order for the latest version to be installed.
How can I ensure that Python 3.11 is installed on my machine?
I've tried to access the dir C:\Program Files\WindowsApps to have a look, but Windows says I don't have permission despite that I am logged in as admin and Read & Execute permissions in 'Advanced Security Settings for WindowsApps' (I have posted another question about that on Super User)

The simplest thing might be to close and reopen your promt to see if your path has been updated. After that, I would alter my user path to point to only the version of python I wanted to use. Close and reopen the terminal. Did you install python for all users or just your user?

You can have more than one interpreter installed on your machine, just installed in different directories. The PATH environment variable determines which directories are considered (and in which order to check) when locating executable names. Likely the directory containing the python3.10 executable has higher precedence than python3.11 or python3.11 is missing from the listed paths.

@JonSG I actually close the CMD window and typed in python -v again, but it spits out the same thing.

@flakes Thanks for this info. The question remains; How can I ensure that Python 3.11 is installed on my machine?

Check the PATH variable as mentioned above see link

@user19077881 As shown in the first screenshot, the path is C:\Users\USERNAME>python -v. What other PATH should be used ?

This question is similar to: Which version of Python do I have installed?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question is similar, but the answers do not address the issue OP has - which is arguably more basic.

Don’t put Python in the path at all.  Python installs the Python Launcher on Windows that can manage multiple installations of python

@KalamalkaKid "C:\Users\USERNAME>" is not your PATH, that's your current working directory. The PATH value separate. It is a list of directories like C:/path/to/bin:C:/other/path/bin:..., which are used to locate executable names.

@KalamalkaKid, Did you try python --version command in cmd?

The Python version which shows when running python -v is the one that's in the PATH first. If you are trying to ensure that it's installed, simply navigate to your PATH directory and look for it, most likely python@3.11 or similar. If you are trying to switch your default interpreter, see this post.

Maybe you just need run CMD as Admin then command python -v again. It worked for me.
